# Node.js tcpsocket on('data') event

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I have a question about Node.js tcp socket and on('data') event.

For example, my client sends data to socket with the very very long message `socket.write('<VERY LONG MESSAGE>')`;

The server is listening port and receiving that data.

Could the `<VERY LONG MESSAGE>` be received with server `data` event not from its start byte? (For example to be chunked by 3 or more parts).

I know about coalescing messages but what about chunking?

Should I implement the received data size validation and coalesce result of few `data` events results for my socket or `socket.write` usually sends messages without chunking?

Comment: Data can always be chuncked, even if the sending side send none chuncked.  but the first bytes will be in the first chunk, chunks should come in the correct order etc.  TCP is a guaranteed protocol in this sense,  UDP on the other hand requires more care..

Comment: It means that `data` event could be fired few times at the server (for 1 client write operation)?

Comment: Yes,.. you will always need to handle chunks.

Comment: But 1 of my chunks with `data` event every time will have desired start byte? I'd like write protocol start-byte to recognize package inside noise AND after the start byte the 4-bytes message size. Is it enough for correct protocol reading implementation?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.. But lets break this down..  If say the client sent the world  `HELLO`, in theory this could be broken down into 2 chunks.   chunk 1 = `HEL`  chunk 2 = `LO`..  Of course in practice such a short message would likely be sent in one,.  but basically your events should go ->  data,data.........end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, chunking on both `write` and when receiving a payload internally can happen.

Sockets are managed by the operating system kernel. Since network I/O can take time they typically use two queue buffers for sockets; one for sending and one for receiving data. Because of that chunked message sizes may vary with different platforms.

Test for yourself:

```
const net = require("net");
var server = net.createServer({
    allowHalfOpen: false,
    pauseOnConnect: false
}, function(serversideSocket) {
    console.log("socket connected");
    serversideSocket.on("data", function(data) {
        console.log(`got data of size ${data.length}`);
    });
    serversideSocket.on("end", function() {
        console.log("client disconnected, closing");
        server.close();
    });
}).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1", function() {
    console.log("server listening");
    var clientsideSocket = net.createConnection({
        port: 1337,
        host: "127.0.0.1",
        allowHalfOpen: false
    });
    var sendBuffer = Buffer.allocUnsafe(1048576);
    clientsideSocket.write(sendBuffer);
    clientsideSocket.end();
});
```

Here's my output:

```
server listening
socket connected
got data of size 65536
got data of size 65536
got data of size 65536
got data of size 65536
got data of size 65536
got data of size 65536
got data of size 65536
got data of size 65536
got data of size 65536
got data of size 65536
got data of size 65536
got data of size 65536
got data of size 65536
got data of size 65536
got data of size 65536
got data of size 65536
client disconnected, closing
```

Comment: Good answer but could be a noise inside tcp socket between chucks? Should I resolve that collision?

Comment: Good answer.. `Sockets are managed by the operating system kernel.`, I'd also like to add, it's not just the OS, it's your router, it's your service provider, it's the server on the other side of the world.

Comment: `noise inside tcp socket`  You can't get noise in TCP sockets, it's a guaranteed protocol.  If the sender sends  `1,2,3,4`  The receiving end if it gets all the bytes will receive `1,2,3,4`...

Comment: Indeed :),  the internet as we know it would be a big pain, if everyone had to handle these things.  Here is a snippet from wiki on TCP that says it all really -> `TCP is a reliable stream delivery service which guarantees that all bytes received will be identical with bytes sent and in the correct order. `

Comment: Does It mean that every chunk will be delivered otherwise the whole message will be canceled?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154574/discussion-between-keith-and-featureoffuture).